# Custom CRM/Mailing/Info.php causes WSOD when installing extensions

Tags: extension, drupal-rules

I'm using the custom PHP feature of CiviCRM to apply patches etc I can't do with a hook.

I have a custom version of CRM/Mailing/Info.php which causes problems when installing an extension. I get the (redacted) error ...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class CRM_Mailing_Info in /custom-code-area/CRM/Mailing/Info.php on line 0, referer: https://example.org/civicrm/admin/extensions?action=add&id=nz.co.fuzion.accountsync&key=nz.co.fuzion.accountsync
```

When I remove that PHP file, all is well.

**Potential culprit**

I see that civicrm_rules_civicrm_postProcess() in drupal/modules/civicrm_rules/civicrm_rules.module on line 132 has ...

```
  require_once 'CRM/Mailing/Info.php';
```

Could that be the cause? Assuming this is called before the custom code is included.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few files across the system that cannot be over-ridden via the custom php directory. This is primarily because these files are included during the bootstrap process.

I dont think anyone has documented which files or tried to minimize the number of files that can be overridden. I suspect all component Info.php files fall in  this bucket and hence you get the above error

Curious as to what custom code you are adding to the Info.php file

Comment: The New Mailing form's recipients field is s-l-o-w and I'm trying to minimise the # of previous mailings that get fetched from 500 to 50. See line 108.

Comment: I think your short term option is to hack that file directly

Comment: Yep. I expect that form will get some extra love from Tim and Coleman in the near future. So I'm happy for a short-term hack.